# creating a pivot_table fails on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe with columns `year`, `month`, `source`, ... there are multiple records per (year,month,source) and I need to generate a pivot table whose index is (year, month) and source is the column and count of the records per (year,month, source) are the values. I have the following code

```
df.privot_table(index = ['year','month'], columns = ['source'], aggfunc = np.size, fill_value = 0)
```

here is how my data look like

```
2001,02,A, ....
2001,02,A,....
2001,03,B,....
2001,03,B,....
2001,03,B,....
```

and this is how I want the data to be

```
           A  B
2001, 02,  2, 0
2001, 03,  0, 3
```

but it throws the following error message

```
 Reindexing only valid with uniquely values index objects
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you provide data and code that generates this error?  I am not able to duplicate your issue by what is described in this question.

Comment: edited my original post

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output can be reached by using `aggfunc=len`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[2001, '02', 'A'], [2001, '02', 'A'], [2001, '03', 'B'],
                   [2001, '03', 'B'], [2001, '03', 'B']],
                  columns=['Year', 'Month', 'Source'])

res = df.pivot_table(index=['Year', 'Month'], columns='Source',
                     aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)

print(res)

Source      A  B
Year Month      
2001 02     2  0
     03     0  3
```

Comment: Looks like either (1) something went wrong when you copy-pasted the code from my answer, or (2) your data isn't comparable to what's here. If (2), you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50261000/edit) your question with a [mcve] with data presented as in my answer.

Comment: this is just a sample of data I have....I can't show the entire table. But when I'm group by (year,month, source) it looks fine.

Comment: @H.Z., Sorry, I can't solve a problem I can't *see*.

Comment: Do you know the reason i’m getting this error message? After applying the pivot_table, there should be unique index